# Interfacing thorlabs equipment with pylablib

Tags: python

I'm trying to use pylablib to access a thorlabs motor using python3.6 but I can't open the device

the documentation seems simple, but I'm new to python and can't work out what I'm doing wrong.
https://pylablib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.apidoc/pylablib.aux_libs.devices.html#pylablib.aux_libs.devices.Thorlabs.KDC101

```
import pylablib as pll
from pylablib.aux_libs.devices import Thorlabs
with Thorlabs.KDC101("27254309") as stage:
    stage.get_status_n()
```

I get the error

> File "...\backend.py" line 674, in **init**
>        raise self.BackendOpenError(e) 
>   pylablib.core.devio.backend.BackendOpenError:
>   Device Not Opened

can anyone please suggest to me how I might be referring to the motor wrong or what I might be able to try?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I know this probably isn't gonna help but I had a similar problem and then after five minutes realized the motors weren't turned on. Felt pretty stupid.

Edit: another issue I had was that when I installed `pylablib`, I simply used:

```
pip install pylablib
```

Instead, you need to do this:

```
pip install pylablib[devio,gui]
```